# Memory reference code (MRC)

Tags: bios, uefi

Что такое по сути своей MRC, это отдельный модуль в БИОСе или это отдельная микросхема? Я не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

Как повелось - отвечаю на свой же вопрос. 
MRC это по сути своей обычный программный код, который нацелен на инициализацию постоянной (она же оперативная) взамен временной (а именно "Cash as RAM") памяти, которой процессор пользуется сразу после запуска кода в микросхеме BIOS.